# OpenLayers filter on null and 0

Tags: openlayers-2

I have this filter:

```
var filter_unset = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
        property: attribute,
        value: 0
 });
```

Now, I want the filter to apply on null values as well, something like:

```
        value: 0 or NULL
```

Can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this but I think you can define two filters and set a parent filter with the OR-Operator:

```
var filter_zero = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
    property: attribute,
    value: 0
});

var filter_null = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.IS_NULL,
    property: attribute
});

var parent_filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR,
    filters: [filter_zero, filter_null]
});
```

Could you give it a try?

EDIT1: using OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.IS_NULL instead of OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EqualTo

Edit2: Added jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/6t047qww/

Comment: I think filter_null might not work for non-existing properties...

Comment: Try to change the line `type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO` to `type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.IS_NULL` and delete the line `value: null` in **filter_null**.

Comment: @taudorf: thanks for the hint. I updated my answer above+ added a jsfiddle with the updated code

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with fields in a table that one would think they're emtpy strings but are in fact NULL :

- only a `select...where fieldname is null;` will retrieve these rows
- a `select ... where fieldname ='';` returns nothing...

In my Javascript code, I had to change it a bit and it works :

```
//somewhere in the main code...
filter = {"fieldname", ""};
...
...
...
//somewhere in an object called method...
this.filter = filter;
for (let key in filter) {//actually, always only one property...
    if("" !== filter[key]) {//Yoda notation, good habit...
        this.filter = new ol.format.filter.equalTo(key, filter[key]);
    }
    else {
        this.filter = new ol.format.filter.isNull(key);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.